# foreign key camel case issue in postgres on heroku server

Tags: sql, postgresql, ddl, quoted-identifier

i am creating table on heroku successfully but the problems is foreign key when add foreign key it will automatically created in small letter by default
postgres accept foreign key  like `serviceId` format

this is my table

```
CREATE TABLE service_categories (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    "serviceId"                 integer   NOT NULL,
    service_category_name       VARCHAR ( 50 )  NOT NULL,
    "createdAt"                 TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NOW(),
    "updatedAt"                 TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NOW()
);
```

but on heroku its created `serviceid` rather then `serviceId`
any body can help how can i create foreign key like `serviceId`

Comment: The tag `sql` says: "...and a tag for the DBMS implementation (e.g. MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, etc.) being used." **Please correct the tags**   Or do you work with `mysql` AND `postgresql` ?????

Comment: Please share the code that you are using (or trying) to create this foreign key, and the table definition of the table you are creating a foreign key to.

Comment: Using quoted identifiers is strongly discouraged. Bit if you create the table with the code in your question (using the dreaded double quotes) then the case **will** be preserved and the column will be named `"serviceId"`. If it isn't, then I guess something in your toolset removes the double quotes

Comment: i am using `"serviceId"` like this but i do not know why its not creating as per expectation

Comment: As I said: if run like that, Postgres **will** create a mixed case column name. [See here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=69ef080eaca9320dab77aeec57a35d5f) - if it doesn't there is something in your tool chain that prevents this.

Answer (score 0):

just double quotes in the model like

```
const Order = db.define("my_orders", {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
    },
    "serviceSubCategoryId": {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
    },
   "userId": {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
    }
   
});
```